# c++ string literal concatenation by juxtaposition

Tags: c++, parsing

The code

```
std::string str = "Hello " "world";
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

compiles and prints `Hello world`. Similarly,

```
char chr[] = "abc" "def" "ghi";
std::cout << chr << std::endl;
```

prints `abcdefghi`. How and why does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is behavior covered by [lex.phases]/6

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

So before the compiler actually starts to compile the code all string literals that are only separated why white space are concatenated together.

```
"hello " "world";
"hello "                  "world";
"hello " 
"world";
```

All produce `"hello world";`

Answer (score 3):

String literals that are separated by whitespace only are automatically concatenated [see cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal)